# How can I select a row and column of a GridLayout Kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to build an app to show parking spaces.

[The design I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BemfS.png)

I'm working in a .kv file to build the GUI, but I don't know how to put the images in the column and row that I would like to do.
Can you help me with this Layout positions?

**main.py**

```
# File name: main.py

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

# Version of kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')


class Main(AnchorLayout):
    parking_space_available = ''
    parking_space_busy = ''

    def update(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
# File name: main.kv
<Label>:
    font_size: 20
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: main_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: label_total
            text: 'Parking spaces total: '
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top':1}
        Label:
            id: label_available
            text: 'Parking spaces available: '
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top':.3}
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            rows: 6
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 0.15, 0.2
                Image:
                    source: root.parking_space_available
                Image:
                    source: root.parking_space_available
                Image:
                    source: root.parking_space_available
        Button:
            text: 'Update'
            font_size: 20
            on_press: root.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code example :

```
class Grid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        GridLayout.__init__(self, rows = 3, cols = 3);
        self.Images_list = list();
        for i in range(self.rows):
            dummy = list();
            for j in range(self.cols):
                dummy.append(Image());
                self.add_widget(dummy[-1]);
            self.Images_list.append(dummy);
        print(self.Images_list);
```

You may try this. The idea is that : if the size of the `GridLayout` is 3 x 3, then when you add the 2nd widget to the `GridLayout`, it will be at row 1 and column 2. So, `GridLayout` 'moves' moves to the right. Knowing this *pattern*, you can first make a list of empty images of `Image` object, `self.Images_list`. `self.Images_list[0][0]` is the image at row 1 - column 1 of the Grid, `self.Images_list[0][1]` is the image at row 1 - column 2 of the Grid, and so on..

`self.Images_list[i][j]` is the image at row i+1 - column j+1 of the Grid.

So if you want to change the image at row 2, column 3 for example, you may access `self.Images_list[1][2].source`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the semicolons are not needed to end the lines.
in python, the carriage return does the job.
here, you've written a one lined program

Answer (score 1):

Kivy's GridLayout, unlike many other GUI Frameworks, don't allow you to choose which specific row/column you want to put the children in. Instead it fills up a row before starting on the next row.

You can however create your own custom GridLayout using IDs.

For example

```
class CustomRow(FloatLayout):
     pass

class CustomGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass


<CustomRow>:
     FloatLayout:
         id: 0
     FloatLayout:
         id: 1
     # etc, creating as many FloatLayouts as many number of columns you want.

<CustomGrid>:
     CustomRow:
        id: 0
     CustomRow:
        id: 1
```

Then in the py file of CustomGrid

```
class CustomGrid(FloatLayout):

     def add_child_to_specific(self, row, col, widget):
         self.ids[row].ids[col].add_widget(widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Grid with 2 columns and 1 row:

```
Grid = GridLayout(cols=2, row=1)
```

If you don't give row argument, it will automatically add rows based on its child.